# Генерирование случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне от -20 до 20

Tags: java, генерация-случайных-данных

Помогите переписать данный код, чтоб генерирование случайных чисел было в диапазоне от -20 до 20

```
System.out.println("Введите размер массива: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random r=new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
n = in.nextInt();

arr = new int [n];
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    arr[i] = (int) ( Math.random()* n);
    for (int i: arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Random mRand = new Random();
int countRandom = 10;
int arr[] = new int [countRandom];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "int random - " + getRandomInt(-20, 20));
}


//вывод случайного значение между мин и макс (Java)
private   int getRandomInt(int min, int max){
    return mRand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

Можно без массива

```
int countRandom = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < countRandom; i++) {
    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "int random - " + getRandomInt(-20, 20));
}
```

Comment: +1, но зачем в вашем коде массив? И я бы не создавал `Random` на каждой итерации.

Comment: @VladD   ну да (: , действительно. Random вынести, массив убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать Random(System.currentTimeMillis() % 41 - 20); Таким образом, у нас будет остатки от 0 до 40, далее отнимаем 20, получится от -20, до 20.

Comment: Попробуйте,  и добавьте получившееся как блок кода.